# Inequalities with multiple variables : Find out the range of another variable

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given that $-1 \le v \le1,-2 \le u \le -0.5 \ and -2 \le z \le-0.5 \ and \ w=\frac{vz}{u} ,$ then what is the range of values for $w$?

I solved this question by trial and error method i.e. by plugging in the values of $v,u \ and \ z$ in the equation $w=\frac{vz}{u}$ to find the maxima and minima of the function. But it feels like a tedious method and not a reliable one.

Can someone please help me with a better solution or approach for this question?

Comment: The denominator of $ \ w \ $ is _always_ negative, so what value for $ \ u \ $ would let you make the ratio as large as possible? as small as possible?  Is it ever possible for $ \ vz \ $ to be positive?  How large a positive number could it ever be?  What is the _most negative_ product $ \ vz  \ $ could ever be?

Comment: $z/u$ is always positive. So we can take max value of $|z|$ which is $2$ and min of $|u|$ which is $0.5$. Then $v=1$ should give max of $w$ and $v=-1$ should give min.

Comment: @boojum : thanks for such a quick response..but I solved the question by that way only...and for $w$ to be minimum $v=1,z=-2$ and $v=-0.5$ which gives $w=-4$ and similarly I have done for the maximum $w$. But is there any other approach other than this way of putting in the variable and finding the range?

Comment: To extend what I was saying $|w| = |\frac{zv}{u}| = |v| \frac{z}{u}$. So to maximize $|w|$, we maximize $z/u$ and $|v|$, which is $4$. $v=1$ gives maxima and $v=-1$ gives minima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the range would be symmetric about $0$ due to the range of $v$.

Now, let's consider the largest value that $\left| \frac{z}{u} \right|$ can take. Let's make $|z|$ as large as possible and $|u|$ as small as possible, the maximum value is $\frac{2}{0.5}=4$.

Hence the range of $w$ is $[-4,4]$.

Answer (score 0):

What you described in your comment is essentially all you need to do for a solution.  If you want something a bit more formal, you could write, for instance:

Case I: $ \quad   0 \ \le \ v \ \le \ 1 $
$$ 0  \ \le v \ \le \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 0 \ \ge \ vz  \ge \  -2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 0 \ \le \ \frac{vz}{u} \ \le \  \frac{-2}{-0.5} \ = \ +4 \ \ ;  $$

Case II:  $ \quad   -1 \ \le \ v \ \le \ 0 $
$$ -1  \ \le v \ \le \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 0 \ \le \ vz  \le \  +2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 0 \ \ge \ \frac{vz}{u} \ \ge \  \frac{+2}{-0.5} \ = \ -4 \ \ .  $$

Hence, $ \ -4 \ \le \ w \ \le \ 4 \ \ . $